# how to display line number outside source code between begin_src and end_src when org file being exported as html?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

NOTE: I do not know how to name my following requirement more clearly.

In org-mode, I write the following text:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp -n
abstract class IntQueue {
def get(): Int
def put(x: Int)  (line:put)
}
#+END_SRC
line (line:put) is a function named put.
```

after being exported as the corresponding html, I hope to get the following contents:

```
1: abstract class IntQueue {
2: def get(): Int
3: def put(x: Int)
}
line 2 is a function named put.
```

I do know how to write the org file's contents about `(line:put)`, so that `line (line:put)` in org file will change into `line 2` in html. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: See http://orgmode.org/manual/Literal-examples.html

Comment: @artscan Thanks! in fact, I have already read the part of the link you mentioned, I only got the name(`put`) of (line:put) , but I wanted line number. Now I got it, I must use '-n -r' if I want the line number.